# C# show property in textbox depending on combobox selecteditem

Tags: c#, combobox, textbox

I have maybe an easy question but I would like to ask about possibilities how to bind textbox Text property to combobox SelectedItem property. I do it through combobox SelectedItemChanged event and set text like this:

```
if(cmbMeasuring.SelectedItem != null)
    txtMethod.Text = ((ListBoxItem)cmbMeasuring.SelectedItem).Value;
```

I have class ListBoxItem which holds 2 strings "Name" and "Value". Then I created BindingList for combobox:

```
private BindingList<ListBoxItem> lst;
```

and then set combobox data source in constructor:

```
cmbMeasuring.DataSource = lst;
    cmbMeasuring.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

This works fine but I dont know if its the best way how to do it. But problem occurs when I change the textbox content. I do it through textbox Leave event:

```
private void txtMethod_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbMeasuring.SelectedItem != null)
        ((ListBoxItem)cmbMeasuring.SelectedItem).Value = txtMethod.Text;
}
```

If textbox lost focus I assign item value. But I have also a menustrip to save input and when I click to it directly this event dont occur so the last input is not saved. I know that this could be done through textbox TextChanged event but it consume a lot of time.

Do you have any better solutions or is it OK? Im not using WPF.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Click event for the `MenuStrip` item, you can do the following

```
MyMenuStripItem.Focus();
```

This should cause the `MenuStrip` item to gain focus and therefore causing the `TextBox` to lose focus.

Comment: Yes Im doing it this way. But tell me if there is some possibility to bind textbox Text to combobox SelectedItem directly maybe as propertynotifychange. I mean if there is another and better way or not.

Comment: I think what you are referring to is a WPF aspect and you state you are not using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try data binding on the TextBox in your form's constructor:

```
txtMethod.DataBindings.Add("Text", lst, "Value", 
                           false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```